# headphone jack for early 2008 macbook air (1,1)

Tags: macbook-pro, headphones, microphone

is the headphone jack on this mba a TRRS one, i.e. does it also work with iphone-like microphone + headphone set? can you point to some official source?

Comment: does it have 4 rings ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 the iphone jack with 4 rings fits in, but I'd like to be pointed to some official specs page from Apple if possible

Comment: I misunderstood then. I looked up your system specs and it says it is not a combo type (no microphone).

Comment: @Buscar웃 hmm, but did you find an official source? because everymac says it has no ext mic, but i doubt its exactness

Comment: @Buscar웃 you were right: both Apple official page and everymac's one say it has no external iphone mic support; thanks

Comment: make that in a answer so we can close the topic

Answer (score -1):

I think it is. You can check for yourself by opening System Information on your MacBook (alt-click the Apple logo in the menu bar and choose System Information), click on Audio (in the Hardware section on the left) and click Intel High Definition Audio. If the Headphone section mentions Combined audio-output (or even easier, if it mentions iPhone Headset) then you will be able to use a headset.

*My own Mac's language is not set to English, so the exact translations might be slightly different, but you'll get the point.

Comment: I don't have OS X installed anymore, otherwise the question would be pointless